# Live CD fails to boot: asking all remaining processes to terminate

Tags: installation, 13.04

I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 7. Using CD, when I click on 'Install Ubuntu', it shows me "asking all remaining processes to terminate" message and the boot CD is ejected. The system boots with Windows again  and I'm not able to install Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: Could you tell the make and model of your computer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it seems that you are trying to install ubuntu from windows.
If you really want to do this, it is possible, but you should use [WUBI](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows).

Otherwise, for the classic installation, you should select the BOOT from the CD (if it isn't automatic at the reboot, change the selection in the [BIOS](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm)), and then you can proceed with the usual installation.